# Align text over background image

Tags: html, css

I have an image in that I want to place text over the top but in specific areas, the text is dynamic so can't be saved as a static image. And the image isn't the full width of the so i can't just fix it to 100% width.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. But I've been trying different things and although I can position text over it's very random in terms of the spacing.

I've tried multiple different ways, but can't get it to work consistently across different screen sizes. If I drag the screen onto a higher res then the text moves.

Within my CSS I have tried different spacing and positioning, like absolute or relative but can't get it to work.

```css
.rank{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 90px;
    left: 90px;
  }
  
.score {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 90px;
  }
  .custom-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/368/560" style="width:368;height:560px;" alt="scorecard">
  <div class="rank"><p class="text-white display-6">#1</p></div>
  <div class="score"><p class="text-white display-6">135</p></div>
</div>
```

But I get the same issues. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is make the container display property to relative so that it is positioned relative to the body and make the text absolute . It makes the text to stick with the image exactly where you want.

You are adding position in pixels change it to relative value(%) . The main problem here is margin. You have to change it to relative value like 1% otherwise it will take a constant value. Also change the font size to a relative value. I recommend using `vw` (vertical height/width) which resizes the font-size according to it's parent.  Comment down if you have any doubts. Thank you.

```css
.container {
           
            margin: 3%;
            position: relative;
        
        }
        .container img
        {
       
        width:70%;
        height:60%;
        }
  
        .first-txt {
        font-size:4vw;
        margin-top:1%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0%;
            left: 1%;
            color:white;
        }
  
        .second-txt {
         font-size:4vw;
        margin-bottom:1%;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 2%;
            left: 1%;
            color:white;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
   
</head>
  
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg" >
        <p class="first-txt">
           your text
        </p>
          
        <p class="second-txt">
           your text
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Expand the snippet(full page) , inspect and change styles for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help Manoj. ITs almost there, but the text still moves when i drag the page from 1 screen to another with different res. Would this be because the image doesn't span the full width?

Comment: "moves" means is it staying in it's original position with same font-size or position is changing when you resize the screen? . I have updated the answer (changed the font size as 4vw) check it's working or not .

Comment: I mean the position of the text changes. But I think this is because the background image is responsive, so changes size based on the screen res. When I load the page on a small screen the text is not in the correct place.

Comment: But in my code snippet it's working fine. The text at the top is sticking with the small cloud and when you resize it font-size is getting smaller . Have you tried changing font size?. You do one thing make a code sandbox and share the link here .I will check it.

Comment: I think this is because of the image in the snippet is 100% width and therefore the actual container is always the same. Does it work for you if you make the image only 1/4 of the width?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251142/discussion-between-manoj-bhat-and-tommyautomagically).

Comment: Sorry, Manoj. I had a conflicting `container` which was breaking this. I have it working now. Sorry for the confusion. And thanks very much for your help.